# How to write a filter query in azure search to access specific field(collections)?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I have azure search REST API response below

```
  My REST API Query is 
    https://myresource.search.windows.net/indexes/myresume-index/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&queryType=full&count=true&search=*
Response
        {
            "@odata.context": "https://myresource.search.windows.net/indexes('myresume-index')/$metadata#docs(*)",
            "value": [
                {
                    "@search.score": 1,
                    "id": "Lakshmi_11",
                    "LastName": "Sripuram",
                    "Profile": null,
                    "Profiles": null,
                    "Education": [
                        "{\"certificate_degree_name\":\"ITI\",\"major\":\"MCA\",\"Institute_name\":\"Chaitanya Insitute of Technology\",\"starting_date\":\"04/07/2010\",\"completion_date\":\"24/4/2012\",\"percentage\":65.6,\"cgpa\":6}"
                    ],
                    "Experience": [
                        "{\"is_current_job\":\"Yes\",\"start_date\":\"24/2/2018\",\"job_title\":\"Senior SAP Developer\",\"enterprise_name\":\"Infosys\",\"job_location_city\":\"Hyderabad\",\"job_location_state\":\"Telangana\",\"job_location_country\":\"India\",\"description\":\"I have an experience in Testing field\"}"
                    ],
                    "Skills": [
                        "{\"skill_set_id\":1258,\"skill_level\":\"High\"}"
                    ],
                    "IsRegistered": false,
                    "rid": "MOY0ALzMD6UBAAAAAAAAAA=="
                },
                {
                    "@search.score": 1,
                    "id": "Preethi_12",
                    "LastName": "DasaraRaju",
                    "Profile": null,
                    "Profiles": null,
                    "Education": [
                        "{\"certificate_degree_name\":\"ITI\",\"major\":\"ITI\",\"Institute_name\":\"valaboju engineering college\",\"starting_date\":\"18/05/2014\",\"completion_date\":\"20/04/2016\",\"percentage\":85.2,\"cgpa\":9}"
                    ],
                    "Experience": [
                        "{\"is_current_job\":\"Yes\",\"start_date\":\"24/3/2019\",\"job_title\":\"PegaDeveloper\",\"enterprise_name\":\"Wipro\",\"job_location_city\":\"Pune\",\"job_location_state\":\"Maharastra\",\"job_location_country\":\"India\",\"description\":\"I have an experience in .NET Technologies\"}"
                    ],
                    "Skills": [
                        "{\"skill_set_id\":1587,\"skill_level\":\"Low\"}"
                    ],
                    "IsRegistered": false,
                    "rid": "MOY0ALzMD6UCAAAAAAAAAA=="
                }
```

Is it possible to write a query from experience field where job_title equal to "PegaDeveloper". Here I need to show only the experience field with job_title.Anyone please help me regarding this I tried with filter query in

```
azure search given below but it is not working.
https://myresource.search.windows.net/indexes/myresume-index/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&queryType=full&$count=true&$select=Experience&search=&$filter=Experience.job_title eq "pegadeveloper"
```

Comment: I noticed that the text to filter on is in lowercase (`pegadeveloper`) in the query whereas in the document it is camel case (`PegaDeveloper`). Can you try by changing the query accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is create an index where certain fields are "complex".
I believe currently, you have modeled the "Experience" field as a collection of strings.

This means that a query like `Experience.job_title eq "xyz"` would not be semantically equivalent to your actual scenario.

Currently, the ability to create indexes with complex fields (complex types or collection of complex types) is in preview, and will be generally available very soon. I'd advise you to go to this [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6670910-modelling-complex-types-in-indexes) page to learn more.